# QML Keyboard Shortcut Click Button

Tags: button, qml, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to add a keyboard shortcut to my QML but I am having a hard time getting it working without repeating logic. Below is the code,

```
Controls.Button {
    id:sendAction
    Shortcut {
        sequence: "Ctrl+Return"
        onActivated: parent.trigger()
    }
    onPressed: {call function}
}
```

If I repeat the calling of the function, the keyboard shortcut works but with `parent.trigger()` it fails with trigger isn't a property of the button. I have tried looking up what functions can be called in a shortcut to trigger the parent but the documentation is quite light. Essentially what I need though is what to add in to `onActivated` to trigger the `onPressed` without repeating the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with the code below.

```
Item {
    Shortcut{
        id: sendShortcut
        sequences: ["Ctrl+Enter", "Ctrl+Return"]
        onActivated: sendAction.action.trigger()
      }

    }
Controls.Button {
    id:sendAction
    action: Controls.Action {
        onTriggered{
            call function
        }
    }
    onPressed: action.trigger()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the pressed signal?

onActivated: parent.pressed()

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#pressed-signal

Comment: I have and it unfortunately doesn't work. I tried pressed, clicked, released, and everything else on that list that would make sense, none of them worked.

Comment: can you post a minimal verifiable example with the problem? I can't deduce the problem just from the snippet you posted.

Comment: I ended up finding the solution and posted it below. Thank you for your help though.